# How To Send Parameters By Submitting An HTML Form In A NodeJs Application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

---

I'm trying to send parameters by submitting the form from the page "**index.html**" to the "**Page2.html**" passing the request through the node server.js

This is my index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script>



</script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="Page1.html?v=1&s=2" method="get">

<input type="submit" value="submit"/>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Server.js:

```
'use strict';
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var urlm = require('url');

//var mymodule = require("./hello.js");
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;


http.createServer(function (req, res) {
var path = urlm.parse(req.url).pathname;
switch (path) {


    case '/':
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        fs.readFile('index.html', function (err, data) {

            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                res.write("<h1>Page Not Found</h1>");
                res.end();
            }
            else {
                res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                res.write(data);
                res.end();
            }

        });
        break;
    case '/Page1.html':

        fs.readFile('pages' + path, function (err, data) {

            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                res.write("<h1>Page Not Found</h1>");
                res.write(req.url);
                res.end();
            }
            else {
                res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                res.write(data);
                res.write();
                res.end();
            }

        });
        break;

    default:
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.write("<h1>Everything is working Fine</h1>");
        res.end();
        break;
}

}).listen(port);
```

Page1.html in which i want to print parameters:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>

    var url = new URL(url_string);
    var parameter = url.searchParams.get("v");
    console.log(parameter);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And, i'm having an output "localhost:myport/Page1.html?"
No parameters and an empty console log in Page1.html,as i'm a beginner in nodejs i tried to solve it as much i could but failed.

Comment: I'm not sure where to start. First of all, node isn't involved in passing the parameters right now, at all. Secondly, in your Page1.html, `url_string` isn't defined. If you replace that with `location.href`, you should see a `1` logged in the console as expected. Most importantly however, form content is usually sent to and processed on the server, i.e. node. I have no clue what your actual goal is here. I'll also recommend to not cobble together DRY violating static file serving but using a proper framework like [express](https://expressjs.com/).

Comment: url_string would be the current href in Page1.html by using window.location.href maybe

Comment: Uhhh... yes, that's what I just told you. I don't know what you're trying to achieve, nothing really makes sense here. You simply ignored 80% of my previous comment, so communicating with you is only going to get worse, I'm afraid. So, bye.